# How can I get JSON from WebSQL

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, web-sql

I have a little app, that uses WebSQL for data's storage.
I want to sync this data with web-server (PHP+MySQL)
My main problem that I have no idea how can I create a JSON from WebSQL to transfer it.

```
//view the result from DB on a web-page
    $('body').html('<ul id="dataAllHere"></ul>')
     mybase.init.getAll = function(){
           var database = mybase.init.db;
           database.transaction(function(tx){
                  tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM table", [], function(tx,result){
                         for (var i=0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
                                item = result.rows.item(i).item;
                                due_date = result.rows.item(i).due_date;
                                the_type = result.rows.item(i).the_type;
                                id = result.rows.item(i).ID;
                                showAll(item,due_date, the_type, id);
                         }
                  });
           });
    }

    function showAll(item,due_date, the_type, id){
          $('#dataAllHere').append('<li>'+item+' '+due_date+' '+the_type+' '+id+'</li>');
    }
    mybase.init.getAll();
```

I'm not really familiar with JSON and I'll be happy about any help and advice.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you create an object/array and encode it to json, which looks the same, but string formatted. For your code:

```
var myJson = [];
for (var i=0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
    item = result.rows.item(i).item;
    due_date = result.rows.item(i).due_date;
    the_type = result.rows.item(i).the_type;
    id = result.rows.item(i).ID;
    showAll(item,due_date, the_type, id);

    myJson.push({item: item, due_date: due_date, the_type: the_type, id: id});
}

$.ajax({
    method: 'post',
    data: myJson,
    type: 'json',
    url: 'target.php'
})
```

Comment: TYWM!
Strange, but it tells me that myJson is undefined.

Answer (score -1):

you can simplify the loop if you need to 
just push every thing from the result to json.

```
for (var i=0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
    myJson.push(result.rows.item(i));
}
```

Comment: This should be a comment for the [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17262551/2006429).